# SP Logout Request to IDP

Tags: single-sign-on, spring-saml

i've been POCing IDP initiated SAML and the last piece i cant get to work is the global logout. When the user has gone from IdP to SP (all working fine) and then selects Global Logout, the LogoutRequest is being generated and the browser is being redirected but the sesisonid in the headers is not the IdPsession identifier - how can i invalidate the IdP session?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this url from your SP on global logout. It will terminate IDP session and SP as well.

```
https://server:port/contextPath/saml/logout
```